# Selecting columns from array in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine

I want to select the columns given in an array and then group based on those columns but I can't figure out how to pass array values through select() in Doctrine.  I've tried a bunch of different variations of this and I can't get it to work.  $factors is just a standard array with column names as values.

```
$qb->select(":factors")
   ->from("Table")
   ->where("type = :type")
   ->groupBy(":factors")
   ->setParameter("factors", $factors)
   ->setParameter("type", $type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are not ment to be used in a `SELECT` statement. Read about [prepared statements in PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), Doctrine is just using this functionallity.

They are only used to compare with stored database values, not column or table names. Prepared statements basically help you escape those values used in a query, which could be a bit difficult for strings containing `"` or `'`.

If you want to use your `$factors` array for variable select statments you could just do

```
$qb->select(implode(',', $factors))
```

but in that case you have to **prevent injections attacks by yourself**. Best would be to have a whitelist of allowed values in `$factors`.

Same holds for `GROUP BY` statement.